# Weird distance between margin and cursor (iTerm2 + tmux)

Tags: zsh, tmux, iterm2

I'm running iTerm 2 on 10.8 and I've installed zsh with oh-my-zsh and tmux (both from homebrew). When running zsh in iTerm it's all good, however, as soon as I run tmux, there is this weird distance between the margin and the cursor. What's weird is that once the command is executed, the distance disappears.

You can see it in the following screenshot.

[image]

Any idea what might be causing this? It's annoying ...

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `TERM` both inside and out of `tmux`?

Comment: Hmm ... outside of `tmux` is `xterm-256color` and inside is `screen-256color`. Which one should I change and how?

Comment: Found this issue as well, don't know if it's related or not: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/iterm2-discuss/opWNrwBwtQ0

Comment: Those are the same `TERM` settings I use. It could be an issue with your `zsh` prompt, in which case I'm afraid I can't help.

Comment: Nah, it has something to do with iTerm2. With the exact same settings, it works fine in Terminal.app. However, there the colours are all messed up :-(.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, try

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`
```

in your .zshrc so tmux will recognize you are using utf-8, also setting

```
set-option -g status-utf8 on
setw -g utf8 on`
```

might help.

as a last resort start tmux with the -u option for setting utf-8 this way